# Draw Circles and Curves which connect those circles

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I've a requirement to draw a few Circles and Curves connecting those circles. The circles have to be drawn in rows and columns fashion, so I guess using a GridPane would be a good choice. However, once all the circles have been drawn, how do I add curves to connect circles belonging to different columns on this GridPane?

I cannot use GridPane.add(node, row, column) for curves cuz that would add the curves to GridCells, neither does GridPane have .getchildren.add() method.

Is there a better design to this problem? Should I chose a different Pane that can help me plot circles in rows and columns along with the curves connecting them?

Comment: Shapes (as opposed to controls) generally work better in a plain `Pane` than in a pane subclass that manages layout. You just need to write the code to set the `centerX` and `centerY` of the circles so they sit in a grid.

Comment: Why do you think `GridPane` doesn't have `getChildren().add(...)`, btw? (It won't be particularly easy to use for this scenario, but there's nothing stopping you doing it.)

Comment: @James_D - yes, you're right. I can use getChildren().add(...), however the curves are not plotted correctly. I'm trying to use a plain Pane now, like you suggested. Thanks!